# How to write a conditional query with Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a simple JSON query for Elasticsearch that looks like this:

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": { "match": { "id": "1" }} ,
    "must": { "match": { "tags.name": "a1"}}
   }
}
```

How can I execute the second 'must' criteria ONLY if the value ('a1' in this case) is not empty?

Comment: You better handle it at the time of query construction through the client.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve it using the following -

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "id": "1"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "missing": {
                  "field": "tags.name"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "tags.name": "a1"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think "missing" can be used in the latest versions of elasticsearch.
But one can use Conditional Clauses instead.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/search-template.html#_conditional_clauses