# Conditional query with Elastic Search

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, conditional-statements

My Elasticsearch Index looks like as below.

```
title:The Godfather
year:1972
genres:Crime & Drama

title:Lawrence of Arabia
year:1962
genres:Adventure,Biography &Drama

title:To Kill a Mockingbird
year:1973
genres:Mystery

title:Apocalypse Now
year:1975
genres:Thriller
```

I am trying to write query in elasticsearch which should first check for generes field if it contains & If it does than perform other matching operation on same fields. if generes doesnt contain &, it should skill other matching operation. Basically i am looking  for if condition in Elasticsearch.

below is my query but its doesnt seems to be working fine..

```
{
  "query": {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "regexp": {
                  "genres": ".*&.*"
                }
              },
              {"match": {"genres":   {"query": "Adventure"}}}
            ]
          }
  }
}
```

I was following below suggestion on stackOverFlow.
[How to write a conditional query with Elasticsearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29867301/how-to-write-a-conditional-query-with-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest bool queries, so what you can do is do have a top level bool query only with a should clause, then inside of that should clause, you have two more bool queries. Each of those contains a `must` part, that contains the search for `&` and `whatever else`. Like this

```
bool:
  should:
    - bool:
      must: [ _search for & and whatever else_ ]
    - bool:
      must: [ _search for another criteria_]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: As per ur suggestion, i wrote below Query but its doesnt help me...  


{
 "query": {
  "bool": {
   "should": [{
     "bool": {
      "must": {
       "regexp": {
        "genres": ".*&.*"
       }
      }

     }
    },

    {
     "bool": {
      "must": {
       "match": {
        "year": "1962"
       }
      }
     }
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}